# I am new to blender and when i change from eevee to cycles for some reason the model i am using turns black

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

[image: eevee]

[image: cycles]
model: https://3dwarehouse.sketchup.com/model/d52ca12e-2dda-4d58-8aa8-a8cd6665a3eb/Cajonera-ALEX-Ikea
I am new to blender so i cant add much information

Comment: While files, images, and external links may be helpful additions to questions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be searched for and indexed thus helping future users with similar issues find it.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the .dae version of this model and it was black for me too. If you select the models and look at the materials assigned to it, once clicked, the material preview goes black. I don't understand the technical aspects, so I don't know what's wrong with the materials themselves... But you can just delete all those materials and assign a new one to everything and your model won't be black anymore!

Here is the messy, but not black result:

[image]